# Adding JScrollpane where JPanel is larger then JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

In my project if the user resizes the frame or has a lower screen resolution then the JPanel containing all the information will be larger than the JFrame.

By way of example code:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class scroll{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setBounds(5, 5, 450, 600);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Can someone kindly explain how to add a JScrollPane for this, have look on here and the wider web but cannot seem to find an answer or tutorial for this.

Comment: maybe you should use frame.setContentPane(panel), not just frame.add(panel)

Comment: @Hejun: `JFrame::add` forwards to the content pane.

Comment: @mainsworth: Don't use a `null` layout.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will give your answer:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class panel{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,600));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why would you answer work when the OP's didn't (yes I know), but rather the give the OP a fish, perhaps you'd like to teach him how to fish

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, really helpful to visualise the changes, java isn't the most intuitive programming language.